# Suma y multiplicación de matrices C++, números extraños

Tags: c++, array, matrices

cuando intento sumar o multiplicar dos matrices de dos por dos(de manera simple), los resultados no me parece que tengan nada que ver.

```
#include "matriz.h"

using namespace std;
Matriz::Matriz() {
}

int Matriz::getNValue() {
    return nValue;
}

void Matriz::setNValue(int value) {
    nValue = value;
}

///Generar randoms reales
float randfrom(float min, float max){
    float range = (max - min);
    float div = RAND_MAX / range;
    return min + (rand() / div);
}

void Matriz::makeM(int filas, int columna) {
    ///Setear los reales a dos decimales
    //cout.setf(ios::fixed);cout.setf(ios::showpoint);cout.precision(2);

///Generar matriz
float matr1[filas][columna],matr2[filas][columna],matrM[filas][columna],matrS[filas][columna];

///Llenarla con numeros al azar de -100 a 100
for (int var1(0); var1 < nValue; var1++) {
    for (int var(0); var < nValue; var++) {
        matr1[var1][var] = randfrom(-100.00,100.00);
        matr2[var1][var] = randfrom(-100.00,100.00);
    }
}

///Imprimir las matrices(TEST)
cout << "\nCONTENIDO DE LAS MATRICES\n";
cout << "\tMatriz #1\n";
for (int var1(0); var1 < nValue; var1++) {
        cout << "|";
    for (int var(0); var < nValue; var++) {
        cout << matr1[var1][var];
        cout << "\t|\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ";
    cout << endl;
}

cout<<endl;
cout << "\tMatriz #2\n";
for (int var1(0); var1 < nValue; var1++) {
        cout << "|";
    for (int var(0); var < nValue; var++) {
        cout << matr1[var1][var];
        cout << "\t|\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ";
    cout << endl;
}

///Multiplicacion de las matrices
cout<<endl;
cout << "\tMultiplicacion de las matrices\n";
for (int var1(0); var1 < nValue; var1++) {
    cout << "|";
    for (int var(0); var < nValue; var++) {
        matrM[var1][var]= matr1[var1][var]*matr2[var1][var];
        cout << matrM[var1][var];
        cout << "\t|\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ";
    cout << endl;
}

///Suma de las matrices
cout<<endl;
cout << "\tSuma de las matrices\n";
for (int var1=0; var1 < nValue; var1++) {
    cout << "|";
    for (int var(0); var < nValue; var++) {
        matrS[var1][var]= matr1[var1][var]+matr2[var1][var];
        cout << matrS[var1][var];
        cout << "\t|\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ";
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

[image: Esto es el resultado, lo que me interesa es sumar por ejemplo fila uno columna 1 con su respectivo, según sé no esta mal, pero no entiendo el porque de los números]

Comment: Resolví el problema, era demasiado tonto y obvio(Quizá no tan obvio). Cuando mostraba la segunda matriz en lugar de mostrar los rangos correspondientes sólo seguía mostrando los de la primer matriz, por eso los datos no cuadraban XD

Comment: esos numerous que aparecen son basura, te recomiendo usar un doble `for` para rellenarlos con 0 al inicializarlos.

Comment: Falta la cabecera de la clase `Matriz`...